# how to write the logstash output config to get ABC,AD_EF,123?

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

my log format is:

```
XXX: 03-20 17:52:28:  XXX. * 0 XXX [XXX] [X XX: X]:XXX\tABC:AD_EF:123\t0\tXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\tXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

how to write the logstash output config to get  ABC, AD_EF, 123 ?

output example:
good,ABC,DEF,123

```
output {
    file {
        path  => "/xxx/xxx/xxx/output.txt"
        codec => plain {
            format => "good,ABC,DEF,123"   # how to write this regular expression????
        }
        flush_interval => 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks For All help, but maybe I made a mistake. 
And Finally, I get the answer for my quest:

```
filter {
grok {
    match => {
        "message" => "XXX\t(?<field1>\w+?):(?<field2>\w+?):(?<field3>\d+?)\t"
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your log output seems to have embedded tabs in it, and those tabs bracket your data. This is good, as it means [the `csv` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-csv.html) can pull that out for you.

```
filter {
  csv {
    separator => "      "
    columns => [ 'garbage1', 'good', 'garbage2', 'garbage3', 'garbage4' ]
    source => "message"
  }
}
```

Note, [that is the actual tab character in there](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-csv/blob/master/lib/logstash/filters/csv.rb#L25-L28), which is hard to represent here.

You would then output the content of the `good` field to your file.